# Function (Cubic)

Tags: polynomials

> Show that $x^3-3xbc+b^3+c^3$ can be written in the form of $(x + b + c)Q(x)$, where $Q(x)$ is a quadratic equation.
>   Show that $Q(x)$ is the sum of three perfect squares and $Q(x)$ can never be imaginary.

Using polynomial long divising, I've found
$$Q(x) = (x^3 - 3xbc + b^3 + c^3) \div (x+b+c) = x^2 - (b+c) x + b^2 - bc + c^2$$

How to solve it? Some hints perhaps?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you know how to do polynomial division?

Comment: Yeap. I know how to do polynomial division.

Comment: @Mathxx Then please post the result of the polynomial division here (cf. my answer) into your question so we can help you with the second part. The first one is already done by this.

Comment: I'm stuck at -3bcx-cx there. How? @AlexR

Comment: First you should get $Q(x) = x^2 + O(x)$. Then compute $x^3 - 3xbc + b^3 + c^3 - (x^3 + bx^2 + cx^2) = -(b+c)x^2 - 3xbc + b^3 + c^3$ so
$Q(x) = x^2 - (b+c)x + O(1)$ and compute $-(b+c)x^2 - 3xbc+ b^3 + c^3 + (b+c)x(x+b+c) = \ldots$. Please put all your calculations into the question so I can see where you get stuck.

Comment: Found$b^2-bc-bx+c^2-cx+x^2$. @AlexR

Comment: @Mathxx Fine. Next time please [_edit_](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1246816/edit) your post as I requested. This will put the important information to the top so answerers don't have to read all comments.

Comment: By the way the order of your terms is odd. usually you write a polynomial in $x$ differently, wich makes me think you used W|A since it gives the same odd term order...

Answer (score 1):

Use polynomial long division:
$$Q(x) = (x^3 - 3xbc +  b^3 + c^3) \div (x+b+c)$$
Doing this will show that $Q(x)$ is a polynomial (it *could* have been a rational function) and prove the first assignment. The second one is done analysing $Q(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Now you have done your polynomial division, here is another method for doing that part:

Let $p=x+a+b$, $q=ax+bx+ab$ and $r=abx$, then $a,b,x$ are roots of the cubic equation $$p(y)=y^3-py^2+qy-r=0$$

If you add $0=p(x)+p(a)+p(b)$ you get: $$(x^3+a^3+b^3)-p(x^2+a^2+b^2)+q(x+y+z)-3r=0$$ and substituting for $p,q,r$ (taking the terms in $p$ to the other side) this becomes  $$x^3+a^3+b^3-3abx=(x+a+b)(x^2+a^2+b^2-ax-bx-xy)$$